# How to Elegantly Anchor a Floating Ornament?

Tags: aquarium, betta

I have a floating artificial log for my Betta.  He hides in it, but only if it is oriented perpendicularly to the filter outlet.  I put part of some clean pantyhose inside the return section of the filter and it reduced the flow for a couple of weeks.  However, the log has returned to being oriented towards the filter outlet and my Betta is not happy.

I don't want to use tape, thread or anything hazardous to anchor the log.  I don't want to put anything overly restrictive inside the filter return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to give a decent answer without seeing what the log looks like, and how you want it to be positioned. Can you post some pictures?

Besides that, anchoring usually requires some sort of thread. Nylon thread won't do any harm to your fish and isn't very visible either. And since it's a floating log, you can make it so that the thread is not actually in the water.

So best idea is probably to attach a thread to the log (iff you can't tie the thread to the log, you can use a small nail or staple in the part that is above water). And then tie the other part of the thread to a suction cup and place it against the glass (above the water level).
Then position the cups and thread until you get the log in the desired direction.

There also exists power glue that is save for aquariums. Perhaps you can also use that to attach a thread to the log.